# ggplot - logarithmic axis labels with defined decimal places

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data which has quite some large values and is spread across a large value range. Therefore, I want to display the data on a logarithmic scale. I found the package `scales` and managed to get this plot:

[image]

With this dummy data:

```
dummy <- data.frame(
  x = "A",
  y = 10^runif(100, min = 1, max = 2.5)
)
```

And this code:

```
ggplot(data = dummy, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(
    trans = log10_trans(),
    breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
    labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))
  ) +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size = 16)
  )
```

However, I would like the numbers in the superscript to always have the same amount of decimal places, lets say 1. How can I achieve this with `ggplot2`? I tried to add `format(..., nsmall = 1)` around different parts of the label argument, but this does not work. It seems like I don't really understand the `trans_format()` function. Can anyone help me?

E.g.: I want the axis to be labeled with 10<sup>2.0</sup>, not with 10<sup>2</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `math_format()` function has a `format` argument wherein you can stack another function to format your numbers.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

dummy <- data.frame(
  x = "A",
  y = 10^runif(100, min = 1, max = 2.5)
)

ggplot(data = dummy, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(
    trans = log10_trans(),
    breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
    labels = math_format(
      format = function(x){number(log10(x), accuracy = 0.1)}
    )
  ) +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size = 16)
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! Makes my actual plot 100% prettier :)

Answer (score 2):

Likely not a very helpful answer, but maybe something in this direction could help:

```
dummy <- data.frame(
  x = "A",
  y = 10^runif(100, min = 1, max = 2.5)
)



ggplot(data = dummy, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(
    trans = log10_trans(),
    breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x)
      10 ^ x),
    labels = function(y){sprintf("10^%.1f", y)}
  ) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text = element_markdown())
```

which gives this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! With `labels = function(y) {sprintf("10^%.1f", log10(y))}` I am already one step closer, thanks! Now I just don't manage to use `expression` on the labels due to reasons I don't know. xD

Comment: Uhh, dont ask me about `expression` haha. I almost always try to avoid it... Sorry can't help you there:/